# Applying a function to every cell in a dataframe based of row and column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dateframe whose rows and columns are numbers. Is there a way to apply a function to every cell, based of whatever row and column the cell belongs to. To illustrate, I want:

```
        |     2022    |    2023    |    2024    |
   0    |  f(0, 2022) | f(0, 2023) | f(0, 2024) |
   1    |  f(1, 2022) | f(1, 2023) | f(1, 2024) |
```

Comment: have a look at: [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)  or [pandas.DataFrame.applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

Comment: I'm unclear the way you're notating it appears you want to _create_ a frame using a function given columns and index.

Comment: Question is not pretty clear, what is the intent.

Comment: Apologies if I was unclear. Yes, I want to create a dataframe, where every cell is a function of the column header (in my example, it would be 2022/2023/2024) and row index (0/1). For example, if the function is simply adding the numbers together, then f(0, 2022) = 0 + 2022 = 2022, f(1, 2023) = 1 + 2023 = 2024. 

I have looked at [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html), but I have not found a way to use them that does what I want.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `pd.DataFrame.apply(func, axis)`
You might find the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) helpful

Comment: I think that is the right function, but would I use it to specifically reference the header name and row index? That is the part I am struggling with.